# Shower head releases water every time the toilet is flushed

Tags: shower, bathtub

I installed a new bathroom with a shower (no tub). The shower head releases water every time the toilet is flushed, even though he mixing valve for the shower is off.

The bathroom area was an old porch with a concrete floor, so the water lines for the bathroom run:

1. to the toilet
2. to the future bath sink
3. up a wall into a ceiling bulkhead
4. down to the mixing valve
5. up to the shower head

When I turn the hot water supply off, the problem goes away.

Comment: Very perplexing - could you please provide some more information, namely;
How much water comes out the shower head?
Where is the hot water being turned off?
Do you know the water pressure in your house?
What type of control valve did you install; brand, model? temperature balancing, Was it soldered and if so did you remove the interior components first?

Comment: Temperature balancing,I neglected to remove the parts, I checked them after the fact, it looks O.K., probably damaged, huh?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. I'm going to guess this is possibly water-hammer related, where a high-pressure spike caused by the toilet fill valve shutting is forcing water past the mixing valve. If so, the water would be released **as the toilet stops filling**, and a water hammer arrestor should settle it down, be it new and high-tech with a piston or old (merely an air-filled pipe stub that needs to be drained of accumulated water from time to time.)

If it releases water **at the start of the flush**, I'd have to suspect some sort of vacuum breaker being involved, and getting activated by the sudden drop in pressure when the toilet fill valve opens.

Edit: ahh, your new information is possibly diagnostic - turning the **hot water supply** off stopping it suggests that the casue is probably related to the "anti-scald" function that's pretty much universal in tub/shower valves at this point, which is responding poorly to the pressure drop on the cold line as the toilet fills (and for some reason, doing so even if the mixer is shut off.) You might call the valve manufacturer and inquire if this is expected behavior or a defect of some kind.

If it is expected behavior, and you cannot run a new line that's either larger (for less pressure drop_ or dedicated (so the toilet and shower are not sharing the line) a small pressure tank/accumulator in the bathroom area **should** sort the issue by holding pressure up while the toilet fills.

On third thought, first go though and make **sure** that all the valves in this line are FULLY open. If the problem persists, see if your toilet fill can be adjusted to be slower. Then consider more involved solutions.

Comment: The water releases at the flush & during the fill.